# Is it Possable to Deploy a .bat file via VB.Net Windows Forms WITHOUT Using "ClickOnce" or User's otherwise having to Install it?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, batch-file

The long-winded title pretty much sums up my entire question, but here's what I'm trying to do-

I have a basic batch file that I want to make a GUI for with Windows Forms. Only problem is I need to make it so I can deploy a package that doesn't require any sort of installation process for the user. This is because our users don't have rights to install or run any scripts. Is there a way can I accomplish this?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Let me clarify- I can put this on a shared directory that gives users full access to be able to run the script; I just don't want them to actually have to install anything.

Comment: They can and they do as of right now; I just want to make a GUI for it that doesn't require any sort of installation process.

Comment: So I would deploy as a click-once and then just link the .exe?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62984/discussion-between-brady-and-matt-wilko).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided they have the (appropriate) .NET framework installed and all the dependencies for your application are in the same folder as your exe (and they don't require installation) you can just deploy your exe to the share and get them to run it from there.

You will generally find all the dependencies for your application after compiling in the `Bin\Release` folder

Comment: Thanks Matt, much easier than I previously thought.

Comment: If the .exe will be run from the share, you may have to grant trust to the exe on the local machine.  I'm not sure if that's 100% true.    In newer versions of the framework, exe's run from a network share may already have trust.